# NSManagedObject: Should I use transient or a regular @property?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject, transient

Why not just use a regular @property instead of transient? I don't care about supporting undo.

Comment: Is "transformable" a typo for "transient" in the title? (am typing up an answer assuming so.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need undo, there's a good chance a plain unmodeled @property is better. When explicitly modeling a property as transient, the main differences are:

- Setting the property marks the object as dirty, even though nothing would actually be saved;
- The property is cleared when the object turns into a fault;
- Weird things can happen when merging changes, depending on your chosen merge strategy.

Some experiments working out the semantics of a transient modeled property might be found at https://web.archive.org/web/20160423093331/http://www.2pi.dk/tech/cocoa/transient_properties.html by Jakob Stoklund Olesen. Because that's a dying archive.org link, I'll excerpt some choice tidbits:

- "A transient property ... You should be thinking of it as something *whose value is nil in the persistent store.*"
- "So what are transient properties good for? ... [for] any property you don't need to be stored, but would like undo support for."
- "Another use ... is caching for properties that can't be stored. Cross-store relationships and attributes with unsupported types are the typical examples. Before saving, you convert the property into something that can be stored, and write it to a binary 'shadow' attribute."
- "It is better to imagine transient properties as representing 'something that is nil in the persistent store', than the common 'fancy instance variables with undo'."

A good article and I wish Jakob had left it up.

Comment: Link is broken now :(